# How to Return List of Project Tasks in ActiveCollab

Tags: php, api, activecollab

Sorry this may be a trivial question but I am new to PHP. In the [documentation](https://github.com/activecollab/activecollab-feather-sdk) to retrieve project tasks, the following code is provided to connect to an Active Collab cloud account:

```c
<?php

require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

// Provide name of your company, name of the app that you are developing, your email address and password.
$authenticator = new \ActiveCollab\SDK\Authenticator\Cloud('ACME Inc', 'My Awesome Application', 'you@acmeinc.com', 'hard to guess, easy to remember');

// Show all Active Collab 5 and up account that this user has access to.
print_r($authenticator->getAccounts());

// Show user details (first name, last name and avatar URL).
print_r($authenticator->getUser());

// Issue a token for account #123456789.
$token = $authenticator->issueToken(123456789);

// Did we get it?
if ($token instanceof \ActiveCollab\SDK\TokenInterface) {
    print $token->getUrl() . "\n";
    print $token->getToken() . "\n";
} else {
    print "Invalid response\n";
    die();
}
```

This works fine. I can then create a client to make API calls:

```c
$client = new \ActiveCollab\SDK\Client($token);
```

and get the list of tasks for a given project as shown in the documentation.

```c
$client->get('projects/65/tasks'); // PHP object
```

My question is, what methods/attributes are available to get the list of tasks? I can print the object using `print_r()` (`print` will obviously not work), and what I really want is in the `raw_response` header. This is private however and I cannot access it. How do I actually get the list of tasks (ex: the `raw_response` either has a string or json object)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods to work with body:

```
$response = $client->get('projects/65/tasks');

// Will output raw JSON, as string.
$response->getBody();

// Will output parsed JSON, as associative array.
print_r($response->getJson());
```

For full list of available response methods, please check [ResponseInterface](https://github.com/activecollab/activecollab-feather-sdk/blob/master/src/ResponseInterface.php).

If you wish to loop through tasks, use something like this:

```
$response = $client->get('projects/65/tasks');
$parsed_json = $response->getJson();

if (!empty($parsed_json['tasks'])) {
    foreach ($parsed_json['tasks'] as $task) {
        print $task['name'] . "\n"
    }
}
```